# Compute $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{a+(t-b)^2} \ dt$ for $a,b>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I would like to compute the integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{a+(t-b)^2} \ dt$$
where $a$ and $b>0$ are positive parameters.

Wolfram Alpha is able to provide an answer for the indefinite integral, but is struggeling with computing the definite one

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28t*%281-t%29%29%2F%28a%2B%28t-b%29%5E2%29+dt+

Comment: try to make the title more concise. Just an integral shouldn't be a title.

Answer (score 6):

To the nice posted solutions we can add one more, where we will use the direct complex integration. For the convenience we change a bit the initial integral and denote
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{a^2+(t-b)^2} \ dt$$
so, to get the initial integral we have to change $a^2\to a$ and multiply the answer by $\pi$.
If we make a cut $[0;1]$ in the complex plane, then
$$2I(a,b)=\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_{C_1} \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz=\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_{C_1} \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{(z-b-ia)(z-b+ia)} \ dz$$
where the contour goes around the cut (clockwise; the contour is marked red). To make the contour closed, we added two small circles around $z=0$ and $z=1$, but the integrals along these circles $\to 0$ as the radius of the circles $\to 0$.
Next, we add to the contour the path $[1]$ $(1;R)$ and a big circle of the radius $ R\to\infty$, counter-clockwise (marked blue on the picture).

[image]

Now, we can consider the integral along a big contour: from 0 to 1 along the upper bank of the cut, around $z=1$ (half-turn, clockwise), along the axis X, along a big circle, along the axis X in the negative direction, around $z=1$, and along the lower bank of the cut to the starting point.
When we go around $z=1$ to the axis X (clockwise), $\sqrt{z(1-z)}\to\sqrt{z(z-1)e^{-\pi i}}=-i\sqrt{z(z-1)}$, so our integrand gets the factor $-i$. Integrals along the path $[1]$ cancel each other. Denoting this new contour as $C_2$, we can write
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_{C_2} \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz=\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_{C_1} \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz+\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_R \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz$$
$$=2I(a,b)+\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_R \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz=2\pi i \sum \operatorname{Res}\qquad(1)\,,$$
because we have two simple poles inside our big contour (at $z=b\pm ia$). Integral $\oint_R$ denotes integration along a big circle.
As $R\to\infty$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\oint_R \frac{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz=\frac{-i}{\pi}\oint_R \frac{\sqrt{z(z-1)}}{a^2+(z-b)^2} \ dz\to\frac{-i}{\pi}\oint_R \frac{dz}{z}=2\qquad(2)$$
We have two cases: $b\in[0;1]$ and $b\geqslant1$. Let's consider $b\geqslant1$ first.
$$2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}=\frac{2\pi i}{\pi}\underset{z=b\pm ia}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{(-i)\sqrt{z(z-1)}}{(z-b-ia)(z-b+ia)}$$
$$=\frac{2}{2ia}\Big(\sqrt{(b+ia)(b+ia-1)}-\sqrt{(b-ia)(b-ia-1)}\,\Big)=\frac{2}{a}\Im\sqrt{(b+ia)(b+ia-1)}$$
Using $b+ia=\sqrt{b^2+a^2}e^{i\arctan\frac{a}{b}}$
$$2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}=2\Big((b^2+a^2)((b-1)^2+a^2)\Big)^\frac{1}{4}\sin\Big(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b-1}\Big)\qquad(3)$$
Combining $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$, we get for $b\geqslant1$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(a,b)=\frac{\Big((b^2+a^2)\big((b-1)^2+a^2\big)\Big)^\frac{1}{4}}{a}\sin\Big(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b-1}\Big)-1\,;b\geqslant1\,}\,(4)$$
To get the answer for $b\in[0;1]$ we can again evaluate the residues and define the right branches of $\sqrt{z(1-z)}$; but it easier just to use the fact that the integral is a continuous function of $b\, (b\in[0;\infty))$ at $a\neq0$.
$$\arctan\frac{a}{b-1}\, (b\geqslant 1)\,\to\,\pi-\arctan\frac{a}{1-b}\, (b\in[0;1])$$
because this is the only option to keep the function continuous at $b=1$. So, for $b\in[0;1]$
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\Big((b^2+a^2)\big((b-1)^2+a^2\big)\Big)^\frac{1}{4}}{a}\sin\Big(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{1-b}\Big)-1$$
$$\boxed{\,\,=\frac{\Big((b^2+a^2)\big((b-1)^2+a^2\big)\Big)^\frac{1}{4}}{a}\cos\Big(\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{a}{1-b}\Big)-1\,;b\in[0;1]\,\,}\quad(5)$$

---

As a quick check, let's consider particular cases:

$b>1; a=0$. It follows from $(4)$ that
$$I(0;b)=\frac{2b-1}{2\sqrt{b(b-1)}}-1$$
what coincides with the answer (3rd case) by @Travis Willse (up to the factor $\pi$)

$b=\frac{1}{2}$. It follows from $(5)$
$$I(a;1/2)=\sqrt\frac{1+4a^2}{4a^2}-1$$
what coincides with the answer (2rd case) by @Travis Willse (up to the factor $\pi$ and the change $a^2\to a$).

Also, taking the limit $a\to\infty$ at fixed $b$
$$I(a; b)\to \frac{1}{\pi a^2}\int_0^1\sqrt{t(1-t)}dt=\frac{1}{\pi a^2}B\Big(\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2}\Big)=\frac{1}{8a^2}$$
On the other hand, at $a\to\infty$
$$I(a;1/2)=\sqrt\frac{1+4a^2}{4a^2}-1\to\frac{1}{8a^2}$$

Comment: (+1) This result is nicer than I expected was possible.

Comment: @Travis Willse, thank you! It was important to check the particular cases, so I used the results you got.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Here's a sketch of one method: The substitution $$t = \frac{u^2}{(1 + u^2)} , \qquad dt = \frac{2 u \,du}{(1 + u^2)^2}$$ transforms the original integral in $t$ to the improper integral
$$2 \int_0^\infty \frac{u^2 \,du}{(1 + u^2) (A u^4 + B u^2 + C)},$$
where
$$A := a + (b - 1)^2, \quad B := 2 [a + b(b - 1)], \quad C := a + b^2.$$

If we write $q(v) := A v^2 + B v + C$, so that $A u^4 + B u^2 + C = q(u^2)$, the discriminant of $q$ is $\Delta(q) = -4a < 0$, hence all the roots of the quartic are complex, and we can factor

$$A u^4 + B u^2 + C = (D u^2 - E u + F) (D u^2 + E u + F) ,$$ so that $$A = D^2, \qquad B = 2 DF - E^2, \qquad C = F^2 ,$$ where $D u^2 \pm E u + F$ are irreducible, equivalently, $E^2 - 4 D F < 0$.

At this point we can take either of the following approaches:

- Use the Method of Partial Fractions explicitly to find that our integrand is
  $$\frac{D (D - F) u + EF}{2 E \Lambda} \left(\frac{1}{D u^2 - E u + F} - \frac{1}{D u^2 + E u + F}\right) - \frac{1}{\Lambda} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + u^2},$$ where $\Lambda := (D - F)^2 + E^2$, after which we can integrate each term as usual.
- Use the fact that the integrand of our new integral is even to write it as
  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^2 \,du}{(1 + u^2) (A u^4 + B u^2 + C)} ,$$ and then apply a standard Residue Theorem argument.

In several special cases the computation simplifies significantly:

- When $b \in \{0, 1\}$: $$\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{a}}\right)} - 1\right)$$
- When $b = \frac{1}{2}$, $$\pi \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4 a}} - 1\right)$$
- In the limiting case $a = 0$, $$\pi \left(\frac{2 b - 1}{2 \sqrt{b(b - 1)}} - 1\right) ,$$ provided that $b \not\in [0, 1]$.
- As $a \to \infty$, the integral decays as $$\frac{\pi}{8 a} - \frac{(16 b^2 - 16 b + 5) \pi}{128 a^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{a^3}\right) .$$
- As $b \to \infty$, the integral decays as $$\frac{\pi}{8 b^2} + \frac{\pi}{8 b^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{b^4}\right) .$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the shorthands $$ p = a+b^2, \>\>\>q = a+(1-b)^2,\>\>\>s=a-b(1-b)$$
to integrate
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{a+(t-b)^2} \ dt
\overset{ t=\frac1{1+x^2}}= & \ \int_0^\infty \frac{2x^2}{(px^4+2sx^2+q)(1+x^2)}dx\\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{2(px^2+ q)}{px^4+2sx^2+q} -\frac2{1+x^2} \ dx\\
= &\ \frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt p+\sqrt q}{\sqrt{\sqrt{pq}+s}}-\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{a+(t-b)^2}\,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto\frac{1+u}{2}}{=}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{4a+\left(1+u-2b\right)^2}\,du $$
equals
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\left(\frac{1}{4a+(1-2b)^2+u^2+u(1-2b)}+\frac{1}{4a+(1-2b)^2+u^2-u(1-2b)}\right)\,du $$
or
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-u^2}\left(\frac{4a+(1-2b)^2+u^2}{(4a+(1-2b)^2+u^2)^2-u^2(1-2b)^2}\right)\,du $$
which reduces to the integral of a rational function via $u\mapsto\cos\arctan t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}.$

Comment: what does this reduction mean?

Comment: That the integral has a closed form. $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\,dx $ with $p,q$ being polynomials can always be computed in a explicit form via partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: but you have a $\sqrt{1-u^2}$ which is not part of a polynomial?

Comment: @Guido [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) guarantee that we can transform it into an integral of a rational function.